# Cannot lock pid file /var/run/freeswitch/freeswitch.pid,this is the error when I start my freeswitch on CentOs7

Tags: freeswitch

how can I solve this problem?
Cannot lock pid file /var/run/freeswitch/freeswitch.pid
Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few reason for this.check one by one.

1. check weather /var/run/freeswitch/ directory exist. if not then create it and give appropriate permission using chmod command.
2. check weather freeswitch user have permission to /var/run/freeswitch/ directory.if not then create it and give appropriate permission using chmod command.
3. check weather there is already any freeswitch.pid  exist.if so then delete it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!                                                     In fact，I login as root on CentOS, so probably permission is not the problem. I also check the freeswitch directory, there is no freeswitch.pid, but when I run freeswitch, there comes the error called  Socket Error! Could not listen on :::8021.

Comment: it means you have to change the event socket port.

Comment: socket.conf.xml